# How to handle this combinatorics and game-theory problem?

Tags: arrays, combinatorics, game-theory

### The Question

We are given an integer sequence **S** of size **N** and two players optimally play a game with this sequence, the rules of the game are as follows :

- The players alternate turns.
- In each turn, the current player must choose one or more elements of the current sequence S such that the values of all chosen elements are identical, and erase these elements from S.
- When a player cannot choose anything (the sequence S is already empty), this player loses the game.

We have to find the number of winning moves for the first player in the first turn. If there are no winning moves for that particular sequence and the first player will always lose the game, we have to simply output zero.

For Example, if the sequence is **1 2 2 2**, then the number of winning moves for the first player in the first turn would be 3 as removing any two of the three 'twos' would ensure victory for the first player.

### My Observation

I think first we have to store the number of unique elements and then each element's frequency, then we would have to simplify the sequence to a particular orientation in which victory would be assured for the first player, then we have to simply calculate the number of moves for reaching that orientation using combinatorics. I have observed that if all the elements have equal frequencies, then the first player would win in one move if the number of unique elements is an odd number and would lose every time of the number of unique elements is an even number. But I can't generalize the case in case of unequal frequencies.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the players see the contents of the sequence?

Comment: Yes they are fully aware of the contents of the sequence and they play optimally, I think it can be boiled down to a 'Nim' problem.

Comment: Well, the algorithm then is quite obvious (unless of course I'm missing something): If the umber of different numbers in the sequence is even, the first player will always lose, and if it is odd the first player will always win. Let me know if this is not clear and I'll put a more elaborated answer.

Comment: For the sequence 1,2,2,3,3,3, the number of different numbers is odd but the first player will lose.

Comment: Not quite... The first player removes, say, the single 1. The second player removes the 2 2's. Then, the first player removes the 3 3's. Finally, the turn goes to the second player that does not have anything to select and hence loses. (again, I might had missed something about the rules of the game; did I?).

Comment: If the first player will remove the single one, the second player would remove only one three and leave the other two 3's, thus ensuring his victory. The players can remove any number of elements(non-zero) of a given type.

Comment: I see. Let's check this further... If the second removed only one 3, can the first remove any other 3 (either one or the two remaining)?